# A split random variable problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, transformation

Let $X$ be a random variable with the density function: 
\begin{equation}
f_{X}(t) = \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{1}{2}, & 1 \leq t < 0 \\
\dfrac{1}{9}t, & 0 \leq t \leq 3 \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and $Y$ a random variable defined as 
\begin{equation}
Y = \begin{cases}
X + 1, & \quad X \leq 0 \\
-X, & \quad 0 \leq X \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\\
2, & \quad \dfrac{1}{2} < X < 1\\
4 - X, & \quad X \geq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

How can I find the CDF of $Y$? I'm having a hard time since it is split this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Plot $Y$ against $X$ as in the figure, and compute $F_Y(y)$. For example, $$\Pr\{Y \le 1/2\} = \Pr\{-1\le X\le-1/2\} + \Pr\{0\le X\le1/2\}.$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can ypu explain why this is correct..? I dont quite understand, because this sketch isnt of the density function of y but the value of Y itself.

Comment: @stos1512 Can I say $Y \le 1/2$ iff $-1 \le X \le -1/2$ or $0\le X \le 1/2$?

Comment: @stos1512 This is the sketch of the function $Y$ as defined by you. You have to find the CDF of $Y$ from this sketch by considering appropriate regions for the preimages of $Y$ for different $X$.